# How do I output a netstat command every 2 seconds to a text file

Tags: linux, netstat

I am trying to make the following happen, but having a hard time getting it to work as expected.
Tried using the watch command, but the output is just a mess.
I found the following, but haven't been able to make it work for my needs:

```
watch 2 "netstat -a | grep 20427 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l"
```

I would like to the run the following command and output to a file with the following two columns every two seconds.

```
netstat -a | grep 20427 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc- l

DATE_TIME | NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS
Fri Nov  6 14:57:37 | 5
Fri Nov  6 14:57:39 | 10
Fri Nov  6 14:57:41 | 5
Fri Nov  6 14:57:43 | 2
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.
Take care and be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`watch` is a good tool when you want to… well, to watch. It interacts with the terminal. If you redirect its output to a file then eventually you will find terminal control sequences written to the file. If this is what you tried then such sequences are probably the mess you mentioned.

A straightforward way to run a command in a loop is to… well, to use a loop. :)

You said you wanted to run `netstat | …` "every 2 seconds". In a loop you have two options:

1. You run the pipeline asynchronously, `sleep` for 2 seconds and run the new one; and so on. This way it's almost perfectly "every 2 seconds". But if the execution of a single iteration takes more than the interval, the output from it may appear after the output from the next one, or even interleave with it.
2. You run the pipeline synchronously, `sleep` for 2 seconds and run the new one; and so on. This way it's not "every 2 seconds", it's rather "2 seconds in between". But since there is at most one pipeline running at any given moment, there is no risk the overall output gets mangled.

Note `watch -n 2 'sleep 10; date'` runs `date` about every 10 seconds. The `watch` itself uses the "2 seconds in between" method, not "every 2 seconds".

A loop that runs `whatever` with 2 seconds in between and redirects the output to a file can be:

```bsh
while :; do whatever; sleep 2; done >output_file
```

In your case there are two additional problems:

1. You want a header. Place it in the file first and then append (`>>`) to the file.
2. You want the date to be in the same line as what follows. The output from `date` (even with a custom format) ends with a newline character. You can remove it with `tr`. Or capture the output to a variable (with `$()` which removes all trailing newlines) and print it later.

Like this:

```bsh
echo 'DATE_TIME | NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS' >output_file
while :; do
   date="$(date)"
   printf '%s | ' "$date"
   netstat -a | grep 20427 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
   sleep 2
done >>output_file
```